# Where can I get JB 700 for Devin?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Where can I get the [JB 700](http://gta.wikia.com/JB_700) for Devin, apart from purchasing from the website ?

I received Molly's message that Devin is still waiting for JB 700. Well, the ride is too expensive. Any chance I can get it on the street?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get this car in the *Deep Inside* mission for Devlin, as Trevor IIRC. The car is located at the movie studio (where Michael previously took some guys in a helicopter). You have to beat up an actor, steal his clothes, then take the car back to Mr Weston's garage.

[A guide for the mission, with video walk-through, can be found on IGN.](http://www.ign.com/wikis/gta-5/Deep_Inside)

Comment: `You have to beat up an actor, steal his clothes, then take the car back to Mr Weston's garage.` Only if you care for the gold medal. You can just crash through the front gate, guns blazing, steal the car and escape. But I tend to find the stealthy approach more fun :)

Comment: You have to be Fraklin for the mission.